# jQuery add * to an URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add a `*` after each keyword

Original URL:

`http://w/r/p/peopleresults.aspx?k=Title%3A%22keyword%22%20extFirstName%3A%22keyword%22%20extemail%3A%22keyword%22%20extworkphone%3A%22keyword%22%20extcellphone%3A%22e%22`

and the result should be:

`http://w/r/p/peopleresults.aspx?k=Title%3A%22keyword*%22%20extFirstName%3A%22keyword*%22%20extemail%3A%22keyword*%22%20extworkphone%3A%22keyword*%22%20extcellphone%3A%2222keyword*%22`

**keyword** is a dynamic word that can change!

Comment: And you got the URL from where? Is it a string? From an `href` attribute? The URL of the page?

Answer (score 2):

An odd request. I assume this is leading on to using the `*` as a wildcard in a SQL statement to search for the keywords? If so I'd think very carefully about what you're doing and potential security issues.

```
var url = "http://w/r/p/peopleresults.aspx?k=Title%3A%22keyword%22%20extFirstName%3A%22keyword%22%20extemail%3A%22keyword%22%20extworkphone%3A%22";
url = url.replace("%22%20", "*%22%20");
```

Comment: keyword is a dynamic word that can change!

Comment: You can also use regex to replace the keyword all at once ex: url.replace('/keyword/g', 'keyword*');

Comment: @user472285 that's fine, the code I posted will still work, regardless of the content of the `url` variable.

Comment: I'm not aware of any widely-used-for-the-web DBMS with a SQL dialect that uses `*` as [a wildcard character](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html).

Comment: @Tomalak Access ;) I agree though it's unlikely, but at least wanted to make OP aware as I couldn't think of a logical reason to want to add an asterisk to values passed in a querystring.

Answer (score 1):

No jQuery is needed, just use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var keyword = 'keyword';
var url = 'http://w/r/p/peopleresults.aspx?k=Title%3A%22keyword%22%20extFirstName%3A%22keyword%22%20extemail%3A%22keyword%22%20extworkphone%3A%22keyword%22%20extcellphone%3A%22e%2'
url = url.replace(keyword, keyword+'*', 'g');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#urlID').replace("%22%20", "*%22%20");`

Require that you have an unique ID on your a-tag.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't know exactly what string the "keyword" is, this will add an asterisk to anything surrounded by "%22" (the url encoding for double quotes):

```
url = url.replace(/%22(\w+)%22/g, "%22$1*%22")
```

Input:

```
http://w/r/p/peopleresults.aspx?k=Title%3A%22keyword%22%20extFirstName%3A%22keyword%22%20extemail%3A%22keyword%22%20extworkphone%3A%22keyword%22%20extcellphone%3A%22e%22
```

Output:

```
http://w/r/p/peopleresults.aspx?k=Title%3A%22keyword*%22%20extFirstName%3A%22keyword*%22%20extemail%3A%22keyword*%22%20extworkphone%3A%22keyword*%22%20extcellphone%3A%22e*%22
```